# How to drap item from QTableView to QPushButton?

Tags: qt

I have a QTableView with some rows,and set it
`tableView.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::DragOnly);`

and then I set
`deleteButton.setAcceptDrops(true);`
It seems that I can not drop and release an item from tableView to button. 
What is the problem? How can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.
I have iinherited the QPushButton class and implement

`void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event);
 void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event);`